# Google Maps API for Unity on the server side

Tags: c#, google-maps, unity-game-engine, asp.net-core, maps

The Google Maps for Unity works really nice on the client-side (Unity) but I cannot currently rip off all the Unity related code to include it on my server-side application running on .net core.
Most location-based games such as GO ofc don't run Unity instance on the container so is it actually possible to get the source c# for it?

This way I could match the code in client<->server. Otherwise, I gotta start working on my own Unity integration.

Thanks a lot,

- J

Comment: So you just need a .NET library for Google Maps API?

Comment: Did you mean that you like to get the Maps SDK for Unity c# codes?

Comment: Yeah I want to get the Maps SDK for Unity c# code. I guess I could try to reflect it from the dlls but dunno if that is considered shady business? : ))

Nathan I believe there is no official Google .NET library for Google Maps and then I would need to make my own Unity integration if I want the client and server-side to match.